# Creation of nested array subobjects indexes

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have some objects of following structure:

```
class SubObject {
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
class MyObject {
    public IEnumerable<SubObject> SubObjects { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create an index on the MyObject.SubObjects index (there is a search of the objects):

```
var filter = Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Eq("subObjects.id", someVal);
await Collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

I try to create it following way:

```
var models = new List<CreateIndexModel<MyObject>> {
   new CreateIndexModel<MyObject>("{ subObjects.id: 1 }")
};
Collection.Indexes.CreateMany(models);
```

Unfortunately currently I'm getting something error:
`System.FormatException: 'Invalid JSON input ''.'`

What can be wrong, what can I improve?

Comment: It's  exactly what the error says - invalid JSON. The valid one is `'{"subObjects.id": 1 }'`. The key should be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to quote your field inside the json string.

```cs
var models = new List<CreateIndexModel<MyObject>> {
   new CreateIndexModel<MyObject>("{ \"subObjects.id\": 1 }")
};
Collection.Indexes.CreateMany(models);
```